# Можно ли использовать мощности графического процессора (GPU) от Google Colaboratory на своём веб-сервисе/сайте?

Tags: python, веб-программирование, нейронные-сети, веб-служба, стилизация

у меня есть программа для стилизации изображений, которая запускается через Google Colaboratory: на вход подаётся путь к изображению-контента, которое нужно стилизовать, и путь к изображению-стиля, на выходе получается изображение контента перерисованное в манере изображения-стиля (если хотите, почитайте подробнее про "Нейронный перенос стиля").

Google Colab использую из-за предоставленных там бесплатных мощностей GPU для обучения и работы нейросети.
Хочу превратить эту программу в веб-сервис (сайт), но продолжать использовать мощности GPU от Google Colab. Могу я как-то через свой сайт отдавать изображения Google Colab'у, чтоб он их стилизовал, а потом возвращал результат мне обратно на сайт?

Comment: Что-то я сомневаюсь. Они там где-то год уже следят, чтобы человек за клавиатурой сидел и периодически просят подтвердить присутствие. Чтобы на халяву там не крутили всякое. С таким использованием, думаю, тоже будут бороться.

Comment: Может у кого-то будут идеи как по-другому обучать нейросеть на графическом процессоре, вне зависимости от мощности компьютера пользователя? Тот же Ostagram, кто-нибудь знает как там это реализовано? У них есть какой-то свой собственный сервер с GPU куда посылаются запросы? Можно ли это реализовать обычному человеку?

Comment: Ну обычно да, выделяют для этого сервер или покупают виртуальный. Так то `flask` хотя бы прикрутить не сложно для вызова своего кода.